# Cannot Read 'execute' of undefined Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have an Error:
C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\index.js:33
client.commands.get('verify').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\index.js:33:38)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\robcio\Desktop\BotFolder\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

and my code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./command').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./command/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'info'){
        message.channel.send('Author: ITS ME')
        message.channel.send('Version: Alpha')
    }
    if(command === 'verify'){
        client.commands.get('verify').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
})

client.login('NOT FOR YOU!');
```

verify.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'Verification',
    description: 'Verification',
    execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = 'NOPE';
        const VerificatedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verificated");

        const VerificatedEmoji = '✅';

        let embed = new Discord.MesssageEmbed()
        .setColor('#043927')
        .setTitle('Verificate')
        .SetDescription('Normal Verification')

        let messageEmbed = new message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(VerificatedEmoji);

        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.messsage.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === VerificatedEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(VerificatedRole);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.messsage.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === VerificatedEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(VerificatedRole);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and I don't know how to repair this I think I must execute a 'execute' using const but IDK how to do that
it's pretty anyoing I just want to do pretty simple bot with verification and other stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In verify.js file, the command name is `Verification` but in your main file, you are trying to get `verify` (`..get('verify')`) and execute it. Since it cant find verify command name, it throws an error. This is because you are trying to get `command.name` in the command handler. So in your case, either change the name to `verify` in verify.js, or you try to get `Verification` in the main file since command name is `Verification`.

**Note:** JS is case sensitive, so make sure that both are identical.

Comment: Thanks But it throws another error:

        let embed = new Discord.MesssageEmbed()
                    ^

TypeError: Discord.MesssageEmbed is not a constructor

Comment: You have a typo. `Discord.MessageEmbed()`. You have three 's' in `MessageEmbed`.